# wysiwyg editor deletes <i><i> code when switching from code to visual view ATG BCC

Tags: html, oracle, editor, atg, bcc

My editor deletes the below code:

```
<i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i>
```

i had the project to be delivered last friday and when finally i was implementing it in bcc, i noticed that the editor deleted the code, so i made a micro-site just for the landing page i created.

After consulting with the IT, they said that the problem was the missing space between the opening and closing 'i' tag. and they deployed the code as below, and it didn't delete the code anymore:

```
<i class="fa fa-plus-square"> </i><i class="fa fa-minus-square"> </i>
```

is this a bug of the editor or it was my responsibility to write a white space between?
they added the space with the "space" key of the keyboard, they didn't even use `&nbsp;`

Everything is ok for the company, just wondering if it was my mistake or just a bug of the editor. I had never encountered this kind of problem(?).

Answer (score 0):

The WYSIWYG editor is most likely stripping the empty tags to try and keep the output HTML as clean as possible. This is not a bug as most editors would do this.

There may be a way to configure this in the `EPHOX EditLive!` editor in the BCC but that is not recommended as you'll have to dig through the OOTB configs and it won't be versioned and probably not supported either.

Instead of having a 'space' or a `&nbsp;` in the copy you can put a [`zero width space`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm.) character into the tag to achieve the same layout but without an actual, visible, space.